# How do I shutdown spring security ldap gracefully

Tags: tomcat, spring-security

I'm having the following problem when stopping my Spring based application on Tomcat...

```
SEVERE: The web application [/Toolbox] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I've tracked back what this thread is ...

```
thread: 43 :: Thread-8 :: RUNNABLE
 Trace: 
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:834)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

(there are really 2 threads, Thread-7 and Thread-8, both ldap)

Apparently ldap is not exiting gracefully. I use Spring Security to authenticate (and grab additional data) from the active directory server.  My security xml file is as follows...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://ldap.example.example.com:389" />
    <property name="base" value="dc=corp,dc=global,dc=example,dc=com" />
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=lna.authquery,OU=LDAPGroups,OU=NorthAmerica,DC=corp,DC=global,DC=example,DC=com" />
    <property name="password" value="${example.password}" />
    <property name="pooled" value="true" />
    <!-- AD Specific Setting for avoiding the partial exception error -->
    <property name="referral" value="follow" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userSearch">
                <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                    <constructor-arg index="0" value="" />
                    <constructor-arg index="1" value="(sAMAccountName={0})" />
                    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <constructor-arg value="" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(member={0})" />
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true" />
            <!-- Settings below convert the adds the prefix ROLE_ to roles returned from AD -->
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="userDetailsContextMapper">
       <bean class="com.example.ncc.utilities.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapAuthenticationProvider" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<sec:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http pattern="/images/**" security="none"/>
<sec:http auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" >
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check*" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <sec:form-login login-page='/login.jsp' 
                    default-target-url="/home.html" 
                    authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=true" />
</sec:http>
```

I've seen references to a `shutdownTlsGracefully` parameter on the  [spring documentation site](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/reference/html/configuration.html) but to be honest, I'm not sure how relevant this is in this case, or how to inject the parameter under spring security ldap.

How can I shutdown ldap gracefully and avoid this potential memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the source of the errant threads.  Turning off pooling `<property name="pooled" value="false" />` removed the problem.  Apparently pooling doesn't play nicely with graceful shutdowns.

I'll accept this answer because it worked and no one else responded.  If anyone else has a better/more elegant answer, feel free to respond, and I'll unaccept mine.